# Strange controller behavior involving where some params break my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I built a feature in my app to allow users to search for images that would search the image description,member who uploaded it, and image tags but I have this weird issue where if I search for the name 'jason' it breaks, but a name like 'jesse' works just fine.

Here is my controller

```
  def search_results
    @tattoos = Tattoo.where("description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%") | Tattoo.tagged_with("#{params[:search]}", :any => true ) | Member.where("membername LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%").order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end
```

if i search for 'jason' my app breaks, giving me an 'undefined method' error and the console shows a bunch of stuff not shown if I searched for say, 'jesse'. Im not entirely sure how to word that but here is what I mean.

Search - Jason

```
    Started GET "/search_results?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=jason&commit=search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-23 20:48:26 -0400
  Processing by IndexController#search_results as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"jason", "commit"=>"search"}
  SQL (0.7ms)  SHOW TABLES
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE (name LIKE 'jason')
  Tattoo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tattoos`.* FROM `tattoos` WHERE (description LIKE '%jason%')
  Tattoo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tattoos`.* FROM `tattoos` WHERE (1 = 0)
  SQL (0.7ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (0.5ms)  SHOW TABLES
  Member Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `members`.* FROM `members` WHERE (membername LIKE '%jason%') ORDER BY fullname asc, created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  Member Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `members`.* FROM `members` WHERE `members`.`id` = 7 ORDER BY fullname asc LIMIT 1
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.id = `taggings`.tag_id WHERE ((`taggings`.taggable_id = 43) AND (`taggings`.taggable_type = 'Tattoo')) AND (taggings.context = 'styles' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)
Rendered shared/_image_roll.html.erb (27.5ms)
Rendered index/search_results.html.erb within layouts/application (29.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 523ms
  Processing by ErrorsController#internal_server_error as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"jason", "commit"=>"search"}
  SQL (0.7ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (0.5ms)  SHOW TABLES
Rendered shared/_register.html.erb (483.4ms)
  Member Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `members`.* FROM `members` WHERE `members`.`id` = 7 ORDER BY fullname asc LIMIT 1
  MemberRole Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `member_roles`.* FROM `member_roles` WHERE (`member_roles`.member_id = 7) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tattoos` WHERE `tattoos`.`status` = 'pending'
  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `feedbacks` WHERE `feedbacks`.`approved` = 0
  SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tattoos` WHERE `tattoos`.`status` = 'reported'
Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (87.6ms)
Rendered shared/_login_form.html.erb (2.9ms)
Rendered errors/internal_server_error.html.erb within layouts/application (582.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 587ms (Views: 583.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `member' for #<Member:0x007f0b0ca077b0>):
    1:   <ol class="image_roll">
    2:     <% @tattoos.each do |t| %>
    3:  <li>
    4:         <% unless t.member.nil? %>
    5: 
    6:           <%= link_to image_tag(t.file.url(:small),:alt=>"#{strip_tags(t.description)}, #{t.style_list}, tattoos"), member_tattoo_path(t.member, t)%>
    7:         <% else %>
  app/views/shared/_image_roll.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_shared__image_roll_html_erb__3185787815883689760_69842755443480_3152220748446100192'
  app/views/shared/_image_roll.html.erb:2:in `each'
  app/views/shared/_image_roll.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_shared__image_roll_html_erb__3185787815883689760_69842755443480_3152220748446100192'
  app/views/index/search_results.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_index_search_results_html_erb___3497910042066847338_69842586729040__4333294961394575926'
```

Search - Jesse:

```
Started GET "/search_results?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=jesse&commit=search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-23 20:48:36 -0400
  Processing by IndexController#search_results as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"jesse", "commit"=>"search"}
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE (name LIKE 'jesse')
  Tattoo Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `tattoos`.* FROM `tattoos` WHERE (description LIKE '%jesse%')
  Tattoo Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `tattoos`.* FROM `tattoos` WHERE (1 = 0)
  Member Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `members`.* FROM `members` WHERE (membername LIKE '%jesse%') ORDER BY fullname asc, created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
Rendered shared/_search.html.erb (0.8ms)
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT tags.*, taggings.tags_count AS count FROM `tags` JOIN (SELECT taggings.tag_id, COUNT(taggings.tag_id) AS tags_count FROM `taggings` INNER JOIN tattoos ON tattoos.id = taggings.taggable_id WHERE (taggings.taggable_type = 'Tattoo' AND taggings.context = 'styles') AND (taggings.taggable_id IN(SELECT tattoos.id FROM `tattoos`)) GROUP BY taggings.tag_id HAVING COUNT(taggings.tag_id) > 0) AS taggings ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 40
Rendered index/_tags_list.html.erb (19.7ms)
Rendered layouts/shared/_right_column_std.html.erb (22.3ms)
Rendered shared/_register.html.erb (5.7ms)
  Member Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `members`.* FROM `members` WHERE `members`.`id` = 7 ORDER BY fullname asc LIMIT 1
  MemberRole Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `member_roles`.* FROM `member_roles` WHERE (`member_roles`.member_id = 7) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tattoos` WHERE `tattoos`.`status` = 'pending'
  SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `feedbacks` WHERE `feedbacks`.`approved` = 0
  SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tattoos` WHERE `tattoos`.`status` = 'reported'
Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (13.5ms)
Rendered shared/_login_form.html.erb (2.9ms)
Rendered index/search_results.html.erb within layouts/application (54.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 64ms (Views: 57.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

And the view:

```
<% @tattoos.each do |t| %>
    <% unless t.member.nil? %>

      <%= link_to image_tag(t.file.url(:small),:alt=>"#{strip_tags(t.description)}, #{t.style_list}, tattoos"), member_tattoo_path(t.member, t)%>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(t.file.url(:small),:alt=>"#{strip_tags(t.description)}, #{t.style_list}, tattoos"), tattoo_path(t) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you are using `|` instead of `||` in `@tattoos = Tattoo.where("description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%") | Tattoo.tagged_with("#{params[:search]}", :any => true ) | Member.where("membername LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%").order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)` perhaps that might be part of the issue?

Comment: @JohnnyGrass Be careful there too, though, as [`and`/`or` is *not* the same as `&&`/`||` in Ruby](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/).

Comment: Yup you're right, edited

Comment: posting my comment as an answer

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: It is worse than that because `||` is nothing like `|` either and switching to `||` just introduces a different bug that is harder to notice.

Comment: @muistooshort His original comment said "instead of `||` or `or`". He edited it and now mine doesn't make much sense. I was just pointing out that those two aren't the same either (and would result in different results here since there's an `=`), and of course neither is `|`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I noticed is that you are using `|` instead of `||` in

`@tattoos = Tattoo.where("description LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%") | Tattoo.tagged_with("#{params[:search]}", :any => true ) | Member.where("membername LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%").order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)`

perhaps that might be part of the issue?

Comment: No, that's not the problem but switching to `||` will hide the problem and cause another subtle bug.

Answer (score 5):

The "`|` vs `||`" issue is not your problem. Doing this:

```
Tattoo.where(...) | Tattoo.tagged_with(...) | Member.where(...)
```

will result in an array that is the union of the three input results. Switching to `||`:

```
Tattoo.where(...) || Tattoo.tagged_with(...) || Member.where(...)
```

will just give you `Tattoo.where(...)` since that query will never be `false` or `nil` and the `||` will short circuit as soon as it has non-falsey result; `Tattoo.where(...)` might might be empty but empty and falsey are different things.

Your problem is that you're mixing two different things in one array: `Tattoo` instances from the first two queries and `Member` instances from the last query. Then your ERB assumes that everything in `@tattoos` is a `Tattoo` (or something else that responds to `member`):

```
<% @tattoos.each do |t| %>
  <% unless t.member.nil? %>
```

If your `Member.where(...)` finds anything, then you will have at least one `Member` instance in `@tattoos` and there is no `Member#member` method as the error message indicates:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `member' for #<Member:0x007f0b0ca077b0>):
```

Stop mixing two different classes in `@tattoos` and your problem should go away. Or you could rename it to, say, `@matches` and smarten up your view logic to be able to display both `Tattoo` and `Member` instances.

Answer (score 0):

I would also argue that you should move this logic into the model, which should make it easier to test.

```
# Controller
@search_results = Tattoo.results_for_search(params[:search])
@search_results << Member.results_for_search(params[:search])

# Tattoo Model
def results_for_search(search_term)
  results = where("description LIKE ?", search_term).all
  results << tagged_with(search_term, :any => true)
end

# Member Model
def results_for_search(search_term)
  where("membername LIKE ?", search_term).order("created_at DESC")
end

# Search Results View
<% @search_results.each do |result| %>
  <% if result.is_a?(Tattoo) %>
    ...
  <% elsif result.is_a?(Member) %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```